# Unable to add a second Windows Server 2008 to a NLB cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cluster, nlb

I am trying to setup a 2-node cluster with NLB on Windows Server 2008 R2 standard.

One the first node (node A) I successfully create a cluster containing it. However, when from node A I attempt to add node B to the cluster it fails with the following error message:
"The specified host is already part of this cluster."

I've tried to run the cluster in unicast or multicast mode, but it still does not work.

Any clues as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: How about giving us some more detail, like how are you trying to add the second host; from NLB manager or the command line? If from the command line, what command are you using?

Comment: I am trying to add the second host from the NLB manager.

Comment: By looking at the log, I see the following entries:0019 Error 07/09/2010 13:15:58  ISAXXXXX The interface "{5ECD3987-91C1-48BA-B89B-82B635FFA18C}" is disabled 
0020 Error 07/09/2010 13:16:28  ISAXXXXX The interface "{5ECD3987-91C1-48BA-B89B-82B635FFA18C}" is disabled 
0021 Error 07/09/2010 13:16:28 10.162.20.102 ISAXXXXX Update on this host skipped because of error 0x000000ca

Comment: Do you have the NLB Feature installed on Host B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, this was a user error :-(

Both machines I was using had been installed from an image which already contained identical burnt-in host names.

So I was attempting to add two hosts with the same name (but different IP address) to the cluster. This caused the error message.

Although this was a stupid mistake from my part, the NLB Manager rather cryptic error messages did not really help.

Comment: Hmm... sounds like sysprep was not used, is that correct? If so, you may have problems with the NIC's as well. Each NIC is identified with a unique GUID and I've seen NIC problems with imaged systems where sysprep was not used.